extract a column from the command output even if it blank bash
I am trying to extract 2nd column from a command output
For example:
$ sudo /usr/sbin/pvs
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdc1  vgswap   lvm2 a--   16.00g      0
  /dev/sdc2  rootvg   lvm2 a--   48.00g   2.70g
  /dev/sde            lvm2 ---   32.00g  32.00g
  /dev/sdf            lvm2 ---   32.00g  32.00g

But the issue is some of the disks are not associated to any VG so the VG name is blank, while extracting the output like this
$ sudo /usr/sbin/pvs | awk '{print $2}'
VG
vgswap
rootvg
lvm2
lvm2

I want to extract like this (Blank if it is blank space)
vgswap
rootvg



Related: linux + print the root file system size

Either use an output format designed for post-processing rather than the default that is intended only for user consumption:
$ sudo pvs --reportformat json_std | jq -r '.report[].pv[].vg_name'
vgswap
rootvg



Or ask pvs to get you the value you want in the format you want:
$ sudo pvs --no-headings --config 'log{prefix=""}' -o vg_name
vgswap
rootvg




The default output format can be made more post-processable, by disabling alignment and indentation and changing the separator:
sudo pvs --config $'report{aligned=0 separator="\t"}log{prefix=""}'

Makes it simple TSV as long as values don't contain newlines or tab, which you can then post process with:
Assuming the column for the vg_name always has VG as header:
mlr --tsvlite --headerless-csv-output  cut -f VG

Or:
awk 'NR==1{for (i = i; i <= NF; i++) h[$i]=i; next}
     {print $ h["VG"]}'

Or, assuming the vg_name column will always be the second:
awk -F'\t' 'NR > 1 {print $2}'


Without changing that output format, assuming the device names won't contain newlines or other control characters or multibyte characters and relying on the fact that VG names can't contain whitespace, you could record the offset of the VG string in the first header line to know where to look for the corresponding value in the subsequent lines:
sudo pvs | awk '
  NR == 1 {offset = index($0, "VG"); next}
  {$0 = substr($0, offset); sub(/ .*/, ""); print}'


Using any awk:
$ cat file | awk 'NR==1{n=NF; next} {print (NF<n ? "" : $2)}'
vgswap
rootvg



That just sets n to the number of fields on the first line of output, then prints $2 if there's that number of fields or a null string otherwise for the rest of the lines.
You could alternatively use GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS as you seem to have fixed width fields in your input:
$ cat file | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='13 9 *' 'NR>1{print $2}'
vgswap
rootvg



Replace cat file with sudo /usr/sbin/pvs on your system.
